# Azure media service create create output asset to specific container

Tags: azure-storage, azure-media-services, azure-sdk-.net, azure-container-service

I'm creating an application that uses azure media service. so in order to manage content, I'm trying to upload assets to managed way as below

This was the code I used to create input asset `containerPath` something like `company1/section1`

```
private async Task<Asset> CreateInputAssetAsync(string assetName, string containerPath, IFormFile fileToUpload)
{
    var asset = await _azureMediaServicesClient.Assets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(_appSettings.AzureMediaConfig.ResourceGroup, _appSettings.AzureMediaConfig.AccountName, assetName, new Asset());

    var response = await _azureMediaServicesClient.Assets.ListContainerSasAsync(
        _appSettings.AzureMediaConfig.ResourceGroup, _appSettings.AzureMediaConfig.AccountName,
        assetName,
        permissions: AssetContainerPermission.ReadWrite,
        expiryTime: DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(4).ToUniversalTime());

    var sasUri = new Uri(response.AssetContainerSasUrls.First());

    var container = new BlobContainerClient(sasUri);
    var blob = container.GetBlobClient(containerPath);

    await blob.UploadAsync(fileToUpload.OpenReadStream());

    return asset;
}
```

so the creating output asset code

```
private async Task<Asset> CreateOutputAssetAsync(string containerPath, string assetName)
{
    var outputAsset = await _azureMediaServicesClient.Assets.GetAsync(_appSettings.AzureMediaConfig.ResourceGroup, _appSettings.AzureMediaConfig.AccountName, assetName);
    var asset = new Asset { Container = containerPath };
    var outputAssetName = assetName;

    if (outputAsset != null)
    {
        var uniqueness = $"-{Guid.NewGuid():N}";
        outputAssetName += uniqueness;
    }

    return await _azureMediaServicesClient.Assets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(_appSettings.AzureMediaConfig.ResourceGroup, _appSettings.AzureMediaConfig.AccountName, outputAssetName, asset);
}
```

But when code runs azure SDK throws an BadRequest exception

What was the missing part in my code

Regards

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

If your want use other storage account, you need to `Add secondary storage account` on portal.

[image]

After read .Net SDK, `CreateOrUpdateAsync` will create a new container. So we just use existed container will solve the issue.

[image]

**Test Step.**

1. Create  new container `input` and `output` on portal.
2. Change your code as below.

   ```
    Asset newasset= new Asset();
    newasset.Container = "input";
    newasset.StorageAccountName = "your storage name";
    Asset asset = await client.Assets.CreateOrUpdateAsync(resourceGroupName, accountName, assetName, newasset);
   ```

**Test Result.**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much for the answer. can you a little bit explain how you manage data with those containers. like in a real scenario I create secondary storage for each company and put all assets under the container. can you look for my workflow and help me to get the solution